# reference to all objects in class

Tags: python, class, reference

```
class Rocket:
def __init__(self):
    self.x=0
    self.y=0
def move(self,x1,y1):
    self.x=self.x+x1
    self.y=self.y+y1
def get_position(self):
    return (self.x,self.y)
def shot(self):
    if self.x==other.x:
        if self.y+20>other.y:
            del self
            del other
        else:
            self.y=self.y+20
```

So I want the shot option to check all the objects that in the class. Like if I have `r1`, `r2`, and `r3` that belongs to this class, I want to `r1.shot()` do something like this:

```
if r1.x == r2.x:
    if r1.y + 20 > r2.y:
        # if that's the case, then it stops, if not then it continues to:
if r1.x == r3.x:
    # and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the shot method

```
def shot(self, object2)
```

or ( i don't understand exactly wich language you are using)

```
def shot(self, Rocket object2)
```

and then inside the body of the method use object2.property to do your operations.

When you call the method you have to pass also the object2

```
r1.shot(r2)
```